# How to run python file on terminal command line

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I want to run below python code in Terminal command line. When I run it using command `$ Python3 practice.py` nothing shows up and command returns to current location.

```
def lesser_of_two_evens(a, b):
  if a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0:
      result = min(a, b)
  else:
      result = max(a, b)
  return result
```

Comment: Your program does not display anything, and the function is not even called. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add to your code defined values for a & b and call the function.
Like this:

```
def lesser_of_two_evens(a, b): 
    if (a % 2 == 0) and (b % 2 == 0): 
        result = min(a, b) 
    else: 
        result = max(a, b) 
    return result
x=3
y=7
print(lesser_of_two_evens(x, y))
```

The second thing: 
For python2 use:

```
python practice.py
```

For python3.x use:

```
python3 practice.py
```

There other method to run the script of python:

Add at the first line of you code this line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

If you're using virtual environment :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or python if using python2

And call the script with:

```
./practice.py
```

Comment: What changes do I need to do if I want command line to prompt for input from the user?

Comment: x=int(input("x="))

Answer (score -1):

type in the path where you have store "practice.py" in command

use the command - python practice.py

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I am running the command from the same directory